# Redux-saga-test-plan expectSaga seems to retain state between independent tests

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit, redux-saga-test-plan

I have the below two tests

```
import {put, select, takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

export default class SessionReducer {
    public static readonly _initialState: any = {
        disconnectCounts: {},
    };

    public static reducer(state: any = SessionReducer._initialState, action: any): any {
        // console.log('reducer', action);
        let newState: any;
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'DEVICE_DISCONNECTED':
                newState = {
                    ...state,
                };
                if (!newState.disconnectCounts[action.value]) newState.disconnectCounts[action.value] = 0;
                newState.disconnectCounts[action.value]++;
                newState.error = {
                    type: 'DEVICE_DISCONNECTED',
                    utc: 1,
                };

                return newState;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
}

export function* errorHandler() {
    yield takeEvery(['DEVICE_DISCONNECTED'], function* (action: any) {
        let state = yield select();
        console.log('*********', state);
        if (state.session.disconnectCounts[action.value] > 1) {
            yield put({
                type: 'WATCH_REBOOT_REQUEST',
            });
            // state.session.disconnectCounts[action.value] = 0
        }
    });
}
let action = {type: 'DEVICE_DISCONNECTED', value: '111'};
describe('Handles Error States and Transitions', () => {
    test('Sends watch reboot request when disconnection count threshold met', () => {
        return expectSaga(errorHandler)
            .withReducer(
                combineReducers({
                    session: SessionReducer.reducer,
                }),
                {session: SessionReducer._initialState},
            )
            .dispatch(action)
            .dispatch(action)
            .put({type: 'WATCH_REBOOT_REQUEST'})
            .run()
            .then((result: {storeState: any}) => {
                debugger;

                let session = result.storeState.session;
                expect(session.disconnectCounts[action.value]).toBe(2); // values for error are tested in reducer test
                expect(session.error).toBeTruthy(); // values for error are tested in reducer test
            });
    });
    test('Does not send WATCH_REBOOT_REQUEST when threshold not met', () => {
        return expectSaga(errorHandler)
            .withReducer(
                combineReducers({
                    session: SessionReducer.reducer,
                }),
                {session: SessionReducer._initialState},
            )
            .dispatch(action)
            .run()
            .then((result: {storeState: any}) => {
                let session = result.storeState.session;
                expect(session.disconnectCounts[action.value]).toBe(1); // values for error are tested in reducer test
                // expect(session.currentScreen).toEqual('actionRequiredIdleScreen');
            });
    });
});
```

If you run each test independently, i used .only, they pass but run them without .only and the second test always fails w/ too many values in disconnectCounts

```
  Handles Error States and Transitions
    ✓ Sends watch reboot request when disconnection count threshold met (263 ms)
    ✕ Does not send WATCH_REBOOT_REQUEST when threshold not met (258 ms)

  ● Handles Error States and Transitions › Does not send WATCH_REBOOT_REQUEST when threshold not met

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: 3

      76 |             .then((result: {storeState: any}) => {
      77 |                 let session = result.storeState.session;
    > 78 |                 expect(session.disconnectCounts[action.value]).toBe(1); // values for error are tested in reducer test
         |                                                                ^
      79 |                 // expect(session.currentScreen).toEqual('actionRequiredIdleScreen');
      80 |             });
      81 |     });

      at __tests__/sagas/sagaStateIssue.ts:78:64
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
      at flush (node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
```

What o what am I missing?

Comment: Needs more details, please create a minimal, reproducible example. Show us the saga code. Please simplify the code, remove irrelevant parts, and locate the problem.

Comment: @slideshowp2 thanks, ya I should have taken the time to do so initially.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the reducer and state together in a class is an anti-pattern of redux.

```
const initialState = () => ({ disconnectCounts: {} });
const reducer = (state: any = initialState(), action: any): any => {
```

You are holding on to a single reference for initialState
It's better to have a function that returns a new instance

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-morning-0w4wu?file=/src/testy.test.ts:175-182

Here is a sandbox with the tests running

Comment: will you please elaborate on your anti-pattern comment?  We use the reducer pattern published by Redux Toolkit; I thought that was official?

Comment: @RobelRobelLingstuyl The two patterns in Redux toolkit are utilising the two main utils they have. Which are createReducer which takes a callback with a builder function. The other is createSlice which will produce the actionCreators in an object. There isn't any benefit in putting a reducer inside a class, I haven't seen that pattern anywhere but here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that both tests use the same reference of `SessionReducer._initialState`. When you pass it to the state in `withReducer`, it isn't cloned in any way and so you end up working with the same object in memory.

There is lots of way how to fix it, e.g. you can have a method instead of a property to create the initial object:

```js
_initialState = () => ({disconnectCounts: {}})
// ...
.withReducer(
  combineReducers({
    session: SessionReducer.reducer,
  }),
  {session: SessionReducer._initialState()},
)
```

or you can deeply clone the object yourself in the test

```js
const deepClone = obj => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
// ...
.withReducer(
  combineReducers({
    session: SessionReducer.reducer,
  }),
  {session: deepClone(SessionReducer._initialState)},
)
```